# Pip installation failure - can't find '__main__' module in 'pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl'

Tags: python, pip

I have installed Python at `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32` location and the version is Python 3.7.3.

To install pip, I downloaded `pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)` from pypi.org website and placed it in `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32`. In the command prompt I entered

`cd C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32`

`python pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

I am getting an error as below: `can't find '__main__' module in 'pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl'`

any help on how this error can be resolved?

TIA!

Comment: How does this relate to bitbucket?

Comment: I am trying to install bitbucket CLI which needs pip

Comment: Your python installation should already come with a pip installation. Please delete the `.whl` file from the `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32` folder and just try to run `python -m pip install <your .whl goes here, something like C:\Users\...\Download\pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) - tl;dr it's already installed

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved by performing a Python re-installation. While I selected 'Modify' option, I saw that the 'Add python path to environment variable' was unchecked. I checked this option and performed a re-installation. This installed pip also for me.

Comment: Pip was always installed, it was just not part of your `PATH` variable

Answer (score 0):

to check if python is installed

```
python -V
```

then try this to install pip

```
python get-pip.py
```

check if pip is installed

```
pip -V
```

Answer (score 0):

Your python must have **pip** as default

But otherwise try **`python3`** instead of **`python`** in installation